# Modal called from service is not shown as a modal but as page content in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I'm building a global error handler so it shows a bootstrap modal dialog showing details about the error. I have the following setup:

[image]

The error modal component defines a method called `open()`, its template includes a button (to debug it) that calls the `open()` and everything works fine, the modal is correctly shown with the binded text.

ErrorModalComponent code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { GlobalErrorHandler } from './global-error-handler.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-error-modal',
  templateUrl: './error-modal.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class ErrorModalComponent {

  private _message: string;

  @ViewChild('content') _modalTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(private _modalService: NgbModal, private _globalErrorHandler: GlobalErrorHandler) {
    this._globalErrorHandler.errorEventSource$.subscribe(errorMessage => {
      this._message = errorMessage.toString();
      this.open();
    });
  }

  open() {
    this._modalService.open(this._modalTemplate);
    this._message = "A change test";
  }

  public get message(): string {
    return this._message;
  }
}
```

ErrorModalComponent html:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" (click)="open()">Show Modal</button>
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">It's not you, it's me: unhandled error</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')" data-dismiss="modal">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>We are sorry but something has slipped by and we have an uncontrolled error.</p>
      <p>A notification has been sent to us and we will process it soon.</p>
      <p>{{message}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <div class="col-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" (click)="c('Close click')" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

GlobalErrorHandler code:

```
import { ErrorHandler,  Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  private errorEventSource = new Subject<string>();
  errorEventSource$ = this.errorEventSource.asObservable();

  handleError(error: any) {
    this.errorEventSource.next(error);
  }
 }
```

When I put an exception somewhere in the code the event is captured, the open method called but the modal is not correctly shown and the binded text does not appear. It appears at the bottom of the page and it is disabled and you cannot click anywhere.

I don't get why this difference when calling the same method from two different places. Any hint?

This is the modal after clicking the button:

[image]

And this is the modal after raising an exception:

[image]

Comment: isn't it better to put the HTML/TS of the modal in a dedicated component to make it reusable ? you can use 'componentfactoryresolver' to dynamically load the component and set the message property

Comment: check this link https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader check the `loadcomponent()` method

Comment: @Niladri: the component is just the modal, the button is only for debugging. Removing that all what's left is error modal code.

Comment: @Niladri: is there any reason I would need to call something lik loadcomponent if calling open from the button works?

Comment: this kind of generic error modal appears usually throughout the application , hence if any exception occurs in any component you can pass the exception message to a method like loadcomponent as a param. However I don't think this is the issue here, Have you debugged whether the `this._globalErrorHandler.errorEventSource$` observable is emitting value in the constructor of the component when you throw the exception . Can you share the code where you are throwing the exception?

Comment: @Niladri: yes, the event is thrown and handled by the modal dialog, that's why it is shown in the last image. Everything works as it should but the dialog appears as window content instead of a modal. Adding the code anyway

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem but with a slightly different setup. I had a globalErrorHandler with a "handleError" function. apparently that function executes outside of the angular zone.

I fixed this by running the ngbMdal in zone.runguarded.

```
this.zone.runGuarded(() => {
        this.modalService = this.injector.get(NgbModal);
        const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ErrorComponent);
        modalRef.componentInstance.errorMessage = error.message;
        modalRef.componentInstance.stack = error.stack;
    });
```

Don't forget the injection in the constructor

```
private zone: NgZone
```